# Сonvert List<integer> to Range<integer> in Map

Tags: java, collections, range

I have a Map with the following values:

```
map.of.list={\
  {'2','4'} : '1', \
  {'4','6'} : '2', \
  {'6','8'} : '3' \
 }

@Value("#{${map.of.list}}")
private Map<List<Integer>, Integer> integerMap;
```

How can I convert this to a `Map<Range<Integer>, Integer> rangesMap`?

Type for `Range` is `org.springframework.data.domain.Range`.

Comment: is Range a guava.Range??

Comment: no. it is org.springframework.data.domain.Range

Comment: What's the type of the `map.of.list` data?

Comment: @aioobe `String`

Comment: @misnomer42, oh! That makes the situation slightly more complicated. Could you provide a self-contained example program with the given input as a `String` variable, and a variable to hold the output?

Comment: @aioobe, I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you mean..

Comment: Create a class with a `main` method and a `String` variable containing the sample input, and a `result` variable of the result type. Edit the question and insert that code snippet. This will make your question more clear.

Comment: @aioobe, I have no problem with converting `String` to `Map<List<Integer>, Integer>`, I don't know how to convert `Map<List<Integer>, Integer>` to `Map<Range<Integer>, Integer>`

Comment: Oh, I see. Now the question is more clear. Let me see if I can answer it now. The keys in the `Map<List<Integer>, Integer>`, are they always lists of size 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this setup:

```
// Sample input
Map<List<Integer>, Integer> input = new HashMap<>();
input.put(List.of(1, 3), 5);
input.put(List.of(4, 7), 8);

// Map to hold the result
Map<Range<Integer>, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
```

You can do it using...

### Traditional `for` loop

```
// Code to convert
for (Map.Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> entry : input.entrySet()) {

    // Convert list key to Range
    List<Integer> key = entry.getKey();
    int from = key.get(0);
    int to = key.get(1);
    Range range = Range.rightOpen(from, to);

    Integer value = entry.getValue();
    
    result.put(range, value);
}
```

### Using `entrySet` and `toMap`

```
Map<Range<Integer>, Integer> result = input.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e -> Range.rightOpen(e.getKey().get(0), e.getKey().get(1)),
                Map.Entry::getValue
        ));
```

### Using `forEach` as suggested by [misnormer42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13506939/misnomer42)

```
Map<Range<Integer>, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
input.forEach((keys, values) -> {
    Range<Integer> integerRange = Range.rightOpen(keys.get(0), keys.get(1));
    ranges.put(integerRange, values);
});
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to solve this problem in the following way:

```
public final class ConversionUtils {

    private ConversionUtils() {
    }

    public static Map<Range<Integer>, Integer> convertTo(Map<List<Integer>, Integer> fromProperties) {
        Map<Range<Integer>, Integer> result= new HashMap<>();
        fromProperties.forEach((keys, values) -> {
            Range<Integer> integerRange = Range.rightOpen(keys.get(0), keys.get(1));
            ranges.put(integerRange, values);
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```